# Changing :hover to touch/click for mobile devices

Tags: css, css-animations

I've had a look around but can't quite find what i'm looking for.

I currently have a css animation on my page which is triggered by :hover. I would like this to change to 'click' or 'touch' when the page is resized past width 700px using media queries.

Here is what i have at the moment: http://jsfiddle.net/danieljoseph/3p6Kz/

As you can see, the :hover will not work on mobile devices but i still want to ensure it works the same way just by click, not hover.

I would rather use css if possible but happy with JQuery also.

I have a feeling this is very easy to do but i am just missing something very obvious! Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the css animation:

```css
.info-slide {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  float:left;
  width:100%;
  background:url(../images/blue-back.png);
  height:60px;
  cursor:pointer;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-align:center;
  transition: height .4s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: height .4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: height .4s ease-in-out;
}

.info-slide:hover {
  height:300px;
}
```

Comment: there is a jquery plugin called hoverIntent

Comment: According to MDN, :active is now supported by all versions. Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active So you should be able to use it as a previous answer mentioned.

Comment: How can you see that this is not working on mobile? If I open the jsfiddle link from mobile, I can't see much.

Answer (score 136, accepted):

If you use :active selector in combination with :hover you can achieve this according to [**w3schools**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_active.asp) as long as the :active selector is called after the :hover selector.

```
 .info-slide:hover, .info-slide:active{
   height:300px;
 }
```

You'd have to test the [***FIDDLE***](http://jsfiddle.net/3p6Kz/2/) in a mobile environment. I can't at the moment. 

***correction*** - I just tested in a mobile, it works fine

Comment: w3schools is not the best resource, therefore I'd loke to cite https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Aactive

Comment: This does NOT work on Microsoft Edge on a touch-enabled Windows 10 laptop.

Comment: Ummmm ...sorry? Lol. Yeah Microsoft edge wasn't out yet when I posted this...I think

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on mobile safari. The answer below with onclick="" does the trick though!

Comment: That is all very nice until the user taps the button again to close it and it won't close unless the user taps anywhere outside the button. Try Chrome dev tools responsive view where you have a touch simulator. If it could be somehow done in pure CSS, that another tap on the button closes it, now that would be awesome!

Comment: @lowtechsun I haven't maintained this answer since I posted it. One day I will edit it with cross-browser functionality to include Edge and maybe some stress testing. Thanks

Comment: Check [this](http://editor.javascriptkit.com/?eg=dynamic-css-hover) on mobile or with touch simulator. Trying to achieve the 2nd step, close/open on tap of the hovered item, with this approach. If only the long touch could somehow also be taken care of. If/when you update this let me know somehow, thanks.

Comment: I have a touch-enabled Windows 10 laptop and this works on Edge, for anyone still interested...

Answer (score 18):

You can add `onclick=""` to hovered element. Hover will work after that.

Edit: But you really shouldn't add anything style related to your markup, just posted it as an alternative.

Comment: this worked for me. LOTUSMS's answer didn't - not sure why. maybe a future visitor to this page can enlighten

Comment: It works on safari with `onclick=""`, but then how to de-activate the element? It remains active forever after the first touch, even when touching outside.

Comment: Update 2019 : onclick="" is now deprecated

Comment: @gigabytes on mobile devices, use 'ontouchstart' event instead of 'onclick', then :hover effect will be deactivated.

Comment: does this only work for buttons and not div

Answer (score 13):

```
document.addEventListener("touchstart", function() {}, true);
```

This snippet will enable hover effects for touchscreens

Comment: This deserves some more explanations I think.

Comment: Nice hack, but need to be careful: this can break other specific interactions.

Comment: for me - element needed ":focus" and ":active" too

Answer (score 12):

On most devices, the other answers work.  For me, to ensure it worked on *every* device (in react) I had to wrap it in an anchor tag `<a>` and add the following:
`:hover`, `:focus`, `:active` (in that order), as well as `role="button"` and `tabIndex="0"`.

Comment: The "tabIndex" did it for me, thank you very much!

Answer (score 9):

I got the same trouble, in mobile device with Microsoft's Edge browser. I can solve the problem with: `aria-haspopup="true"`. It need to add to the div and the `:hover`, `:active`, `:focus` for the other mobile browsers.

Example html:

```
<div class="left_bar" aria-haspopup="true">
```

CSS:

```
.left_bar:hover, .left_bar:focus, .left_bar:active{
    left: 0%;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

A CSS only solution for those who are having trouble with mobile touchscreen button styling.

This will fix your hover-stick / active button problems.

```css
body, html {
  width: 600px;
}
p {
  font-size: 20px;
}

button {
  border: none;
  width: 200px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background: #00aeff;
  font-size: 20px;
}

button:active {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

.delayed {
  transition: all 0.2s;
  transition-delay: 300ms;
}

.delayed:active {
  transition: none;
}
```

```html
<h1>Sticky styles for better touch screen buttons!</h1>

<button>Normal button</button>

<button class="delayed"><a href="https://www.google.com"/>Delayed style</a></button>

<p>The CSS :active psuedo style is displayed between the time when a user touches down (when finger contacts screen) on a element to the time when the touch up (when finger leaves the screen) occures.   With a typical touch-screen tap interaction, the time of which the :active psuedo style is displayed can be very small resulting in the :active state not showing or being missed by the user entirely.  This can cause issues with users not undertanding if their button presses have actually reigstered or not.</p>

<p>Having the the :active styling stick around for a few hundred more milliseconds after touch up would would improve user understanding when they have interacted with a button.</p>
```

Answer (score 3):

I am a CSS noob but I have noticed that hover will work for touch screens so long as it's a "hoverable" element: image, link, button. You can do it all with CSS using the following trick.

Change your div background to an actual image tag within the div or create a dummy link around the entire div, it will then register as a hover when you touch the image.

Doing this will mean that you need the rest of your page to also be "hoverable" so when you touch outside of the image it recognizes that info-slide:hover has ended. My trick is to make all of my other content dummy links.

It's not very elegant but it works.

Comment: You're generalizing this a bit much - especially older iPhones don't apply `hover` on a click (but they do apply `active` and `focus`). To my knowledge, it also doesn't depend on the "clickability" of an object, as every element is "clickable" - but I might be wrong, as I haven't seen all devices out there, which is why it's good practice to not just go by observation, but documentation.

Answer (score 3):

Well I agree with above answers but still there can be an another way to do this and it is by using `media` queries.

Suppose this is what you want to do :

```
body.nontouch nav a:hover {
    background: yellow;
}
```

then you can do this by media query as :

```
@media(hover: hover) and (pointer: fine) {
    nav a:hover {
        background: yellow;
    }
}
```

And for more details you can visit [this](https://medium.com/@mezoistvan/finally-a-css-only-solution-to-hover-on-touchscreens-c498af39c31c) page.

Comment: This answer does not explain how to add click functionality.

Answer (score 1):

I think this simple method can achieve this goal.
With CSS you can turn off pointer event to 'none' then use jQuery to switch classes.

```css
.item{
   pointer-events:none;
 }

.item.clicked{
   pointer-events:inherit;
 }
 
.item:hover,.item:active{
  /* Your Style On Hover Converted to Tap*/
  background:#000;
}
```

Use jQuery to switch classed:

```js
jQuery('.item').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).addClass('clicked')l
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a pure-CSS solution and `:active` wasn't exactly what I was looking for because an element will only be active during the click / touch, meaning the hover/active state will either be visible very briefly or, if you keep touching, your finger might cover up the element. Some people might prefer this behavior but in my case I rather wanted a "toggle" and keep the "hover" state once touched, and allow the user to disable the state again by touching the screen somewhere else.

So I went with a `:focus` state and included `tabindex="0"` to make the element focus-able across browsers.

```css
.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.tag {
  display: flex;
  width: fit-content;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
  
  .text {
    background: gray;
  }
  
  .icon {
    position: absolute;
    background: red;
  }
  
  &:hover, &:focus {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">  
  <div class="tag" tabindex="0">
   <div class="text">
    Label
   </div>
   <div class="icon-wrapper">
     <div class="icon">
       Icon
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Obviously, one could further tweak this to enable :focus only in mobile browsers / touch-enabled devices.