# Local links on mobile devices does not work well when hover(tapping) them

Tags: html, css

I have a few local links on the same HTML page. Every one of them is defined as follows:

```
<a class="thumbnail" href="#idn">Anchor text(n)<span id="idn">Span text(n)
```

Where idn=id1, id2,...

The Anchor text is displayed all the time but the Span text should be displayed only when hover on the Anchor text.
So in an style page I made the following definitions:

```
<style>
.thumbnail span {display:none;}
.thumbnail:hover span {display:block;}
</style>
```

On my desktop with windows10 and using no matter what browser it works fine.
On my mobile phone with android and Opera mini the situation is as follows: I asume that a single tap is the same as hover, so I tap on the first link in the page order and the "span" information is displayed very well. I go back and tap on the second link in the page order and surprisingly is displayed the "span" information for the first link. Between the two links is a distance of aproximately 10 rows so I don't think is a matter of confusion.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing :hover to touch/click for mobile devices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22559756/changing-hover-to-touch-click-for-mobile-devices)

Comment: I don't understand very well your answer. As I know an <a> tag can have only four states defined in CSS as :link, :visited, :hover, and :active.