# Mouseover for smart-devices

Tags: javascript, html, hover, mouseover, onmouseover

I want an image to "turn" into another image when hovering. So, basically there is an image (image1.png) on a page, and when hovering it, it should simply show another imagine (image2.png) instead of the first one.
I tried using this and it works perfectly well:

```
<img src='Image1.png' width='100' height='100'
 onmouseover="this.src='Image2.png';" 
onmouseout="this.src='Image1.png';" />
```

None of the images have links, that's why I didn't use any of the "a hover" solutions.

However, now I just realised that it will only work on computers and not on smart devices since they don't really have the hover function. But since the website has quite a few smart device users, it's really important that it works for them as well.

Is there some solution to that?

My JS skills are very limited, so I haven't been able to figure it out yet.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851663/how-do-i-simulate-a-hover-with-a-touch-in-touch-enabled-browsers AND this too :http://www.hnldesign.nl/work/code/mouseover-hover-on-touch-devices-using-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

My personal experience, its better to use CSS for these type of things and you can specify absolute path in CSS no need of links for images (../../.)

Again, you cannot have hover on mobile devices but you can change hover to touch-click. 
This is currently being discussed here: [Changing :hover to touch/click for mobile devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22559756/changing-hover-to-touch-click-for-mobile-devices)