# Change hover to touch

Tags: html, css, hover, touch

I am trying to make [this effect](http://jsfiddle.net/i_like_robots/7GvV2/embedded/result,html,css/) touch-friendly. I have a thumbnail gallery that has titles and descriptions. The title is displayed on load, and when the user hovers over the thumbnail they see the longer description. Then they can click on the entire image to go to the linked page.

I have tried several options, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22559756/changing-hover-to-touch-click-for-mobile-devices) but none seem to work. I'd be fine if the hover acted as a touch to display caption info, and a second touch will open the link that is assigned to the image. Right now, the first touch displays the description for a half second, then follows the link.

I'm open to CSS or js options- I just need to get something to work!

```
.caption {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;

    /* Only the -webkit- prefix is required these days */
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
            transform: translateZ(0);
}

.caption::before {
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: transparent;
    transition: background .35s ease-out;
}

.caption:hover::before {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

.caption__media {
    display: block;
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.caption__overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;

    -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
            transform: translateY(100%);

    transition: -webkit-transform .35s ease-out;
    transition:         transform .35s ease-out;
}

.caption:hover .caption__overlay {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
}

.caption__overlay__title {
    -webkit-transform: translateY( -webkit-calc(-100% - 10px) );
            transform: translateY( calc(-100% - 10px) );

    transition: -webkit-transform .35s ease-out;
    transition:         transform .35s ease-out;
}

.caption:hover .caption__overlay__title {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
}
```

Comment: From what I understand you can have the image in an `<a></a>`, so when they hover it shows the text but when they click it takes them to that page.

Comment: I tried that, but the overlay covers up the image and then you can't follow the link. I want the overlay to cover up the image and stay clickable, which it does right now. I have the <a> just before the image and closed it at the end of the div. I just need it to do that on touch.

Comment: So when hover over image text will show! and the text should be clickable?

Comment: Yes, text should be clickable. It works correctly on hover, but it does not work on touch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably what you're looking for.

```css
.hvrbox,
.hvrbox * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.hvrbox {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 400px;
  height: auto;
}

.hvrbox img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.hvrbox-text a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
}

.hvrbox .hvrbox-layer_bottom {
  display: block;
}

.hvrbox .hvrbox-layer_top {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  color: #fff;
  padding: 15px;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.hvrbox:hover .hvrbox-layer_top,
.hvrbox.active .hvrbox-layer_top {
  opacity: 1;
}

.hvrbox .hvrbox-text {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.hvrbox .hvrbox-text_mobile {
  font-size: 15px;
  border-top: 1px solid rgb(179, 179, 179);
  /* for old browsers */
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(179, 179, 179, 0.7);
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding-top: 2px;
  display: none;
}

.hvrbox.active .hvrbox-text_mobile {
  display: block;
}

.hvrbox .hvrbox-layer_slideup {
  -moz-transform: translateY(100%);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(100%);
  transform: translateY(100%);
}

.hvrbox:hover .hvrbox-layer_slideup,
.hvrbox.active .hvrbox-layer_slideup {
  -moz-transform: translateY(0);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0);
  transform: translateY(0);
}
```

```html
<div class="hvrbox">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/5760/3840?image=1067" alt="Mountains" class="hvrbox-layer_bottom">
  <div class="hvrbox-layer_top hvrbox-layer_slideup">
    <div class="hvrbox-text"><a href="http://www.goolge.com">Take me to Goolge</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```