# Use js variable as img src

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to get js to dynamically generate a thumbnail gallery with titles & descriptions into the divs of [this question I asked earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49948524/change-hover-to-touch).

I thought [list.js](http://listjs.com/) might work best, as it will give me sort and pagination. I used their starter script to try and get my variables into the right divs, but I keep running into problems, especially with outputting an img src.

I want to use the alias as a filename to automatically locate the thumbnail in the correct path- for example, for the alias alias1, the img src would be img/thumb/alias1.jpg. How can I get the javascript to generate this path based on alias and insert it and my other variables into the correct divs?

Here's the code I have. Any ideas on how to make this work, or a better solution?

```js
var options = {
  valueNames: [ 'title', 'alias', 'description', 'url', 'image' ],
  item: '<li><div class="hvrbox"><div class="hvrbox-title"><h5 class="title"></h3></div><div class="hvrbox-layer_bottom"><img id="image"><div class="hvrbox-layer_top hvrbox-layer_slideup"><a href class="url"><div class="hvrbox-text"><p class="description"></p></div><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></a></div></div></li>' };


var values = [
  { title:'Title 1', alias:'alias1', description:'Description of collection 1.', url:'#', },
  { title:'Title 2', alias:'alias2', description:'Description of collection 2.', url:'#', },
  { title:'Title 3', alias:'alias3', description:'Description of collection 3.', url:'#', }
];



  var image = document.getElementById("image");
  var root = 'img/thumb/';
  var x = 'alias';
  var y= '.jpg';
  image.src = root + x + y;


var collectionList = new List('collection-list', options, values);
```

```css
.hvrbox,
.hvrbox * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.hvrbox {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.hvrbox-title {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  margin: 0;
  top: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 12%;
  padding-top: 1.5%;
  padding-left: 1.5%;
  padding-right: 1.5%;
  text-align: center;
}

.hvrbox i {
  position: absolute;
  bottom:2%;
  right:3%;
  font-size: 3em;
  color:#E6AA3C;
}

.hvrbox img {
  width: 100%;
}

.hvrbox-text a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 5px;
}

.hvrbox .hvrbox-layer_bottom {
  display: block;
}

.hvrbox .hvrbox-layer_top {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  color: #fff;
  padding: 15px;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.hvrbox:hover .hvrbox-layer_top,
.hvrbox.active .hvrbox-layer_top {
  opacity: 1;
}

.hvrbox .hvrbox-text {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 75%;
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.hvrbox .hvrbox-text_mobile {
  font-size: 15px;
  border-top: 1px solid rgb(179, 179, 179);
  /* for old browsers */
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(179, 179, 179, 0.7);
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding-top: 2px;
  display: none;
}

.hvrbox.active .hvrbox-text_mobile {
  display: block;
}

.hvrbox .hvrbox-layer_slideup {
  -moz-transform: translateY(100%);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(100%);
  transform: translateY(100%);
}

.hvrbox:hover .hvrbox-layer_slideup,
.hvrbox.active .hvrbox-layer_slideup {
  -moz-transform: translateY(0);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0);
  transform: translateY(0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/list.js/1.5.0/list.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="collection-list">
      <ul class="list"></ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure, because I can't see the file structure, but assuming the js file is in the root of the project ( the same folder that the image folder is inside),  you will need to append ./ Onto the beginning of the file path defined in the root variable.

I hope that makes sense